# Boot from USB, edit system files

Tags: boot, usb, sudo

I made a mistake in my evdev configuration, and now my system won't boot. I can boot from Ubuntu on a USB stick, though. How can I edit the relevant system file as root so that I can boot normally, again? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal and type into it:

```
sudo -H gedit
```

and hit enter.

This will open gedit with the appropriate permissions. Then all you have to do is browse to the document on the hard drive and make the necessary changes.

Comment: It's asking me to sudo apt install gksu, but then I get unable to locate package gksu.

Comment: can you try just sudo gedit, and ignore the warning it gives you?

Comment: or make sure you are connected to the internet and try installing gksu again.

Comment: @TheXed The preferred method now is sudo -H

Comment: I will make that change.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to access root on the device as `sudo su`, whereupon I edited the system file on the hard drive using `vi`. I was then able to resume the normal boot process on the laptop.